ibm_botocore.exceptions.CredentialRetrievalError
I am receiving the following error with the ibm botocore s3 client.
ibm_botocore.exceptions.CredentialRetrievalError: Error when retrieving credentials from https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token: HttpCode(400) - Retrieval of tokens from server failed.

The complete traceback:
Refreshing temporary credentials failed during mandatory refresh period.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/credentials.py", line 2773, in _protected_refresh
    metadata = self.auth_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/credentials.py", line 2685, in _default_auth_function
    raise CredentialRetrievalError(provider=self._get_token_url(), error_msg=_msg)
ibm_botocore.exceptions.CredentialRetrievalError: Error when retrieving credentials from https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token: HttpCode(400) - Retrieval of tokens from server failed.

In my application I am using multithreading to do some objects copy operations.For authentication, I have handled both the hamc and API key logic.
Following is my client code with hmac keys:
client = ibm_boto3.client('s3',
                          aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
                          aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
                          endpoint_url="https://s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud", 
                          config=Config(max_pool_connections=100, connect_timeout=10, read_timeout=600)) 

And for API key:
client = ibm_boto3.client('s3',ibm_api_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
                          ibm_service_instance_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
                          endpoint_url="https://s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud",
                          ibm_auth_endpoint="https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token",
                          config=Config(signature_version="oauth", max_pool_connections=200,
                                        connect_timeout=300, read_timeout=300))

I have verified the credentials they are not expired/deleted. Also, this error occurs intermittently and seems like it gets resolved on the next try. I want to know what causes this and how can I prevent this.
